# inject inline gulp-svgstore into pug (formerly jade)

Tags: svg, gulp, pug, gulp-inject

I'm using gulp-store to inject into pug. I got it to inject into a pug file in the tags/comments but it's on html. How can i make the output in pug syntax?

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var svgstore = require('gulp-svgstore');
var inject = require('gulp-inject');
var pug = require('gulp-pug');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    var svgs = gulp
        .src('src/*.svg')
        .pipe(svgstore({ inlineSvg: true }));

    function fileContents (filePath, file) {
        return file.contents.toString();
    }

    return gulp
        .src('src/svg.pug')
        .pipe(inject(svgs, { transform: fileContents }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a couple months old, but I actually came across your question when I was searching for an answer similar to this, and I figured out a solution I hope could work for your project.

So it seems like you grabbed that code from gulp-svgstore's documentation. First things first, you'll notice that the inject tags they are using are for injecting into HTML:

```
<div class="visuallyhidden">
  <!-- inject:svg --><!-- endinject -->
</div>
```

In order for this to work with Pug, you need to change the tags to:

```
.visuallyhidden
  //- inject:svg
  //- endinject
```

This could be all you needed, but I'd like to share some gulp tasks that I used to combine multiple SVGs into one SVG using `<symbol>` elements that I then injected into a `.pug` template.

### Steps

First I created a `svgstore` task combines multiple SVG files into a single SVG using `<symbol>` tags.

```
gulp.task('svgstore', () => {
  var target = gulp.src('app/includes/svg-defs.pug');
  var source = gulp.src('app/svg/*.svg')
    .pipe($.svgmin())
    .pipe($.svgstore({inlineSvg: true}));

  function fileContents(filePath, file) {
    return file.contents.toString();
  }

  return target
    .pipe($.inject(source, {transform: fileContents}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/includes'));
});
```

The structure of my app looked like:

```
app
  |
  +--includes
  |  |
  |  +--svg-defs.pug
  |  +--header.pug
  +--svg
  |  |
  |  +--svg-1.svg
  |  +--svg-2.svg
  +--images
  +--styles
  +--scripts
```

So any SVG file in the `svg` directory would get combined into a single SVG.

In `svg-defs.pug` I included the inject tags:

```
.svg-defs-container.visuallyhidden
  //- inject:svg
  //- endinject
```

Then in my gulp `serve` task, I had to include a watch for any `.svg` changes in my `svg` directory.

```
gulp.task('serve', ['views', 'styles', 'scripts', 'fonts'], () => {

  ...

  gulp.watch('app/svg/*.svg', ['svgstore']);
  gulp.watch('app/data.json', ['views']);
  gulp.watch('app/**/*.pug', ['views']);
  gulp.watch('app/styles/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
  gulp.watch('app/scripts/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
  gulp.watch('app/fonts/**/*', ['fonts']);
  gulp.watch('bower.json', ['wiredep', 'fonts']);
});
```

I also had to modify the `views` task to run `svgstore` before any of it's logic could run. This is because we want to inject the single SVG into our template before gulp complies our pug into HTML.

```
gulp.task('views', ['svgstore'], () => {
  return gulp.src('app/*.pug')
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe($.pug({pretty: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp'))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});
```

Finally, I just added a simple `include` to my `index.pug` file:
include ./includes/mixin-interior.pug

```
doctype html
html.no-js(lang='')
  include ./includes/head.pug

  body
    include ./includes/browser-support.pug
    include ./includes/analytics.pug
    include ./includes/svg-defs.pug

    ...
```

I used Yeoman's [generator-webapp](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp) to generate my project and `gulpfile.js`. I had to do some customizing to get it to work with Pug, but check out the full `gulpfile` if things don't make sense.

Comment: I figured this workaround, but I was hoping there's a better way